# Populating custom table on Shipment release

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom table and made it available on the Customers screen called 'Serial Tracking'. The purpose of this screen is to track serialised items that each customer is in possession of (regardless of who the item was purchased from).

I would like a record automatically added to the table on shipment release. I have attempted to customise the Release method of SoShipmentEntry but am having trouble getting all the required data together as well as the best way to structure the code.

The custom table DAC is

> AUSerialTrack

[image: example of screen]

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the answer to your question but to long for a comment.

As an alternative, what if you set your Serials tab view to the Ship Line Split table without dealing with a custom table. You could get the information you needed with something like this: (need to convert to your BQL view for your serials tab)

```
SELECT [ship].[CustomerID],
       [ship].[ShipmentNbr],
       [split].[InventoryID],
       [split].[LotSerialNbr]
FROM [dbo].[SOShipLineSplit] split
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SOShipLine] line
        ON [line].[CompanyID] = [split].[CompanyID]
           AND [line].[ShipmentNbr] = [split].[ShipmentNbr]
           AND [line].[LineNbr] = [split].[LineNbr]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SOShipment] ship
        ON [ship].[CompanyID] = [split].[CompanyID]
           AND [ship].[ShipmentNbr] = [split].[ShipmentNbr]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[InventoryItem] i
        ON [i].[CompanyID] = [split].[CompanyID]
           AND [i].[InventoryID] = [split].[InventoryID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[INLotSerClass] c
        ON [c].[CompanyID] = [i].[CompanyID]
           AND [c].[LotSerClassID] = [i].[LotSerClassID]
WHERE [c].[LotSerTrack] = 'S'
      AND [ship].[Confirmed] = 1;
```

Then when the user goes to the tab its always the current results. No custom code to fill in a custom table so easier for upgrades/customization maintenance.